# Dont allow viewpager load two page in the first time

Tags: android, android-viewpager, progressdialog

At the moment, i have a viewpager,when page scroll,i have load api for get new information.
But in the first load viewpager,progress loading display two twice because it load first page and next page.
I only want to load the first page in viewpager.
How must I do?

Comment: If you don't load the next page, when the user starts scrolling the ViewPager, what are you going to show?

Answer (score 4):

best way is to create one interface. and implement this interface to all fragment.
e.g.

```
public interface FragmentInterface {    
    void fragmentBecameVisible();
}
```

- in ur viewpager activity put like this e.g

  ```
  viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

          @Override
          public void onPageSelected(int position){
                  FragmentInterface fragment = (FragmentInterface) mAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, position); 
              if (fragment != null) {
                  fragment.fragmentBecameVisible();
              } 

              actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

          }

          @Override
          public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2){
          }

          @Override
          public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
          }
      });
  ```
- in your fragment like

  ```
  public class TestFragmet extends Fragment implements FragmentInterface {

      @Override
      public void fragmentBecameVisible() {
      // your task to execute
      }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Put OffScreenPageLimit to ZERO. It won't load other fragments.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```