# Refresh fragment when coming back on it in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, reload

I have a ViewPager populated by Fragments. Especially, I have a Fragment that shows a list of Addresses objects and one that allows to create a new Address. 
The process to add a new Address is the following:

***AddressListFragment --> CreateAddressFragment --> AddressListFragment***

So when the new address is added, I come back to the **AddressListFragment** which is then the active one in the ViewPager. I need to update that fragment in order to update the list with the new added address when I come back on it ! Is there a specific method that I need to override on that fragment ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `attach(...)` and `detach(..)` the fragment is only the way to update

Comment: You mean to destroy the fragment and recreate an instance of it ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412379/viewpager-update-fragment-on-swipe/20412875#20412875) post is what you want..?

Answer (score 1):

You should notify your adapter with [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) to update your list like

`yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Yes but where ? Which method of the fragment is called when I come back on it ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. When you change something anywhere and anytime, you can notify adapter in the end and the adapter updates the list.

Comment: Oh I see, I should get the address list binded to the adapter in ***AddressListFragment*** from the ***CreateAddressList***, add the new created address to it and call notifyDataSetChanged right. Will try it out !

Answer (score 0):

In your `AddressListFragment` you can create `Custom Broadcast Receiver` and also register this `Custom Broadcast Receiver` in `AddressListFragment`.
now send `Broadcast message` from `CreateAddressFragment`. when you send message at that time in your AddressListFragment receiver receive the message and you can do your task.

or if you want to create one method that call every time when you back to fragment then you can find best solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942304/dont-allow-viewpager-load-two-page-in-the-first-time/26943543#26943543)